Different java versions available at the same time - how to delete all
I currently have several versions of java on my Mac: 8, 11, 17, 20, and 21.
When I do /usr/libexec/java_home -V, it shows:
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    21.0.2 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 21.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home
    20.0.2 (arm64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 20" /Users/lezoe/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-20.0.2.1/Contents/Home
    17.0.10 (arm64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 17" /Users/lezoe/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.10/Contents/Home
    11.0.22 (arm64) "Homebrew" - "OpenJDK 11.0.22" /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.22/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home

I recently downloaded java version 8.402 and it automatically set that version as default. But I can't find that version anywhere. I also tried to switch to other version using /usr/libexec/java_home -v 11.0.22, but no matter what, when I check current version of java by java -version, it still shows
openjdk version "1.8.0_402"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.402.07.1 (build 1.8.0_402-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.402.07.1 (build 25.402-b07, mixed mode)

I think I messed up something. How can I solve the issue, or how can I uninstall them all to reinstall later?
Thank you so much!
I tried to uninstall version 8., but when I check java -version, it's still there.

In the future, to avoid this problem: SDKMAN!

I am using jenv to handle different JDK in my Mac.
https://www.jenv.be/

